# why UIImageJPEGRepresentation method change the imageData size

Tags: ios

as above,when i use UIImageJPEGRepresentation to 
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.selectedPic, 1.0);
the imageData become large than first?such as from 100KB to 300KB
what's this happen?

Answer (score 1):

That's likely because you're creating a jpeg of the maximum quality (or minimal compression). The 2nd parameter to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` specifies the output image quality on the scale from 0 to 1. Try setting it to different values, like 0.5, and see how it reduces the size of the image data.

Comment: What happens when you changed it to 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are using "perfect quality" (or 1.0 setting for for compression).  Turn it down a notch.  Also, accept some of your previous answers.  13 questions and no accepts is unacceptable.